# Which is make best performance dynamicaly added controls or drag and drop form toolbox?

Tags: winforms

I am new to software programming.

So tell me Which is make best performance dynamicaly added controls or drag and drop form toolbox? and how to calculate performance?

Comment: Time them.  Only time I would expect to see much of a difference is if you have a large number of controls you dont show initially, and may in some circumstances never do so, so it made them for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamically Added a controls make best performance then drag and drop 
dynamic control can be occupy less memory then drag and drop and u can also create HTML controls dynamically...
and other option is you can create your own controls (User controls) also and then use it in your page

Comment: I need more different of these two controls. So i am waiting for that. Surely i accept when those thinks are got.

Comment: ya other is User controls which u used in ur page now check my ans again i edit that